# Flutter Firebase Cloud Functions deleting all items as soon as they are written

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, timestamp, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to use the deleteOldItems Cloud Functions code for my project, when I use the code and simply change the 2 hours to 4 it deletes all my nodes as soon as they are written.  Here is my Firebase functions code...

```
exports.deleteOldItems = functions.database.ref('messages/{pushId}').onWrite(async (change) => {
  var ref = change.after.ref.parent; // reference to the items
  var now = Date.now();
  var cutoff = now - 4 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
  var oldItemsQuery = ref.orderByChild('timestamp').endAt(cutoff);
  return oldItemsQuery.once('value', function(snapshot) {
    // create a map with all children that need to be removed
    var updates = {};
    snapshot.forEach(function(child) {
      updates[child.key] = null
    });
    // execute all updates in one go and return the result to end the function
    return ref.update(updates);
  });
});
```

And here is how I'm saving my timestamp in Flutter to

> database/messages

with child 'timestamp'..

```
var time = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
```

Here is my JSON @ 'messages'

```
"messages" : {
    "-M3e5Glv5JEaz12hDwBB" : {
      "body" : "Hello",
      "name" : "Charles",
      "photo" : "https://media1.giphy.com/media/7wDEaTbCupuRq/giphy-downsized.gif",
      "timeStamp" : 1585549220985,
      "user" : "4eb8920a-e407-4488-bce4-c6f64f7b0891"
    },
    "-M3e5Jfx2cnbtMTNLPev" : {
      "body" : "Example",
      "name" : "Charles",
      "photo" : "https://media1.giphy.com/media/7wDEaTbCupuRq/giphy-downsized.gif",
      "timeStamp" : 1585549232893,
      "user" : "4eb8920a-e407-4488-bce4-c6f64f7b0891"
    },
    "-M3e6oYk6_zTe6IAs0Fg" : {
      "bodyGif" : "https://media3.giphy.com/media/8xomIW1DRelmo/giphy.gif",
      "name" : "Charles",
      "photo" : "https://media1.giphy.com/media/7wDEaTbCupuRq/giphy-downsized.gif",
      "timestamp" : 1585549625584,
      "user" : "4eb8920a-e407-4488-bce4-c6f64f7b0891"
    },
    "-M3hR_DrGcKhM8zpFbYA" : {
      "body" : "Again",
      "name" : "Charles",
      "photo" : "https://media1.giphy.com/media/7wDEaTbCupuRq/giphy-downsized.gif",
      "timeStamp" : 1585605399479,
      "user" : "4eb8920a-e407-4488-bce4-c6f64f7b0891"
    }
```

and my database security rules are as follows for 'messages'...

```
"messages": {
      ".indexOn": ["timestamp"]
         }
```

How can I get the nodes to be removed as expected?

Comment: Are you sure that this is the correct approach to deleting documents? Firebase allows you to run cron jobs which can run at a specific interval, which may be more suitable for your use case. This runs every time a write is incurred in the database, which may happen a lot and incur costs to run the function.

Comment: Please edit your question with a snippet of the JSON at `messages` (as text, no screenshots). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I've added my JSON snippet.  Please answer so that I may have a better understanding of how Functions work.  Also, taking dan's comment into account do you recommend cron jobs for an intermediate developer like myself or is there a way I can simply delete 200 nodes every time 300 has been created?

Comment: Let's first get your current code working, and only then focus on optimizing the invocation count (which is what danwillm commented about). In this case the problem is a simple difference in capitalization: the code uses `timestamp`, while your JSON writes it as `timeStamp` (with an uppercase `S`).